# What is/are best practice(s) to align an HTML checkbox on a web form?

Tags: forms, input, checkboxes, alignment

Consider this HTML form:

[image]

The checkbox in the form is really a pain in the ..., because no matter what you do, it can't be aligned in a good visual form with the rest controls of the form. For example, here are two other possible layouts:

[image]

and

[image]

Them main reason is that, the checkbox label should appear on the opposite side. Even putting it in the correct side doesn't solve the visual non-harmonic layout.

My question is, what are the best practices for checkboxes on the web. Should I replace it with a 2-itemed HTML select control?

Comment: Put a submit button after you check box to maintain the look


i dont know what they will do after knowing whether i am married or i am single??? its completely waste.......

Comment: @Philip, why did you close this question? What I asked was about the concept of **layout** which falls directly with what this site is all about. Layout is one of the fundamental concepts of graphic design.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

form labels should be consistent.

here's one of many solutions (I've used radio buttons which amounts to the same thing as one checkbox, but you could stick with the checkbox)

[image: form]

or you could top align:

[image: form]

edit to add:

http://www.slideshare.net/lukew/web-form-design-best-practices

good advice on form alignments....

Answer (score 4):

One of the most useful ways to align elements on a page (I've found it so, at least), is to use tables. It's pretty simple to sort things nicely into rows and columns, and hide all the borders so that to the user it looks like everything is just lined up nicely. An additionaly benefit is variably sized cells. If something needs more space, give it more space. If a checkbox needs to be all the way to the side, set the td width to something like 5 or 10 % (depending on the size of the row). Some really nice layouts can be constructed this way.

Comment: Thanks @Jim. However, I think in future, [CSS Grid Layout](http://thoughtresults.com/grid-layout) would replace the table (as it's style-based layout instead of markup-based layout)

Comment: Tables aren't a good choice for web layout. They're difficult to edit, difficult to update across multiple pages simultaneously and aren't accessible.

Comment: @Jimmy "difficult to edit" is kind of subjective - I've always found them fairly easy to deal with, although I must agree that updating across multiple pages simultaneously would be a pain. What do you mean when you say they aren't accessible?

Comment: Okay, I need to explain two points:

One: they're difficult to edit because they create a messy HTML page with massive numbers of cell, table and row tags, all over the place. HTML tables are difficult enough to navigate at source level when they contain real data - never mind other divs, forms and paras.

Two: they're not 'accessible' insofar as screen readers and browse-aloud tools have a lot of trouble parsing them effectively. They assume that tables are actual data tables, and that makes the end result quite confusing for those users.

Comment: Dear sweet baby Jesus do NOT listen to anyone who tells you "tables are not accessible." If that was even REMOTELY the case then do you honestly think screen readers would have EVER caught on in the visually impaired community? Screen readers DO/CAN read tables a little differently if the user instructs them to do so. They'll do things like repeat the column headers and such. But other than that, readers will read out the content in the order in the source order, which will be fine. Just make sure you use proper labels.